# Enable button only when both radio groups are selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET controls. In my form, I have 4 radio buttons. One of the radio buttons group names is book the other one is card. My goal is to disable the next button if none of the radio buttons is clicked or if only one of the groups is clicked. To enable the next button the user must select from one of the book options and one of the card options. How can I accomplish this?

**Visual**

[image]

**ASP.NET - HTML**

```
<div style="padding:30px; background-color:antiquewhite;">

    <div style="background-color:aliceblue; width:190px; padding:10px;">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioPassBookYes" runat="server" Text="Book-Yes" GroupName="book"/>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioPassBookNo" runat="server" Text="Book-No" GroupName="book"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="background-color:ActiveBorder; width:190px;  padding:10px;">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioPassCardYes" runat="server" Text="Card-Yes" GroupName="card"/>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioPassCardNo" runat="server" Text="Card-No" GroupName="card"/>
    </div>

    <br>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnNextRecentInfo" runat="server" Text="Next" disabled="disabled"/>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" Text="Check" />
</div>
```

**JS Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var isCheckedPassBookYes = $("#<%=RadioPassBookYes.ClientID%>").prop('checked');
        var isCheckedPassBookNo = $("#<%=RadioPassBookNo.ClientID%>").prop('checked');
        var isCheckedPassCardYes = $("#<%=RadioPassCardYes.ClientID%>").prop('checked');
        var isCheckedPassCardNo = $("#<%=RadioPassCardNo.ClientID%>").prop('checked');


        $("#<%=RadioPassBookYes.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        });
        $("#<%=RadioPassBookNo.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            isCheckedPassBookNo = true
        });
        $("#<%=RadioPassCardYes.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        });
        $("#<%=RadioPassCardNo.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            isCheckedPassCardNo = true
        });


        if (isCheckedPassBookYes === true) {
            $("#<%=BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        if (isCheckedPassBookNo === true) {
            $("#<%=BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID%>").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


            $("#<%=RadioPassBookYes.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                check_selection();
            });
            $("#<%=RadioPassBookNo.ClientID%>").click(function () {
               check_selection();
            });
            $("#<%=RadioPassCardYes.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                check_selection();
            });
            $("#<%=RadioPassCardNo.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                check_selection();
            });

            check_selection();

            function check_selection()
            {
                var isCheckedPassBookYes = $("#<%=RadioPassBookYes.ClientID%>");
                var isCheckedPassBookNo = $("#<%=RadioPassBookNo.ClientID%>");
                var isCheckedPassCardYes = $("#<%=RadioPassCardYes.ClientID%>");
                var isCheckedPassCardNo = $("#<%=RadioPassCardNo.ClientID%>");

                if(
                   (isCheckedPassBookNo.is(':checked') || isCheckedPassBookYes.is(':checked'))
                   && (isCheckedPassCardYes.is(':checked') || isCheckedPassCardNo.is(':checked'))
                    )
                    {

                        $("#<%=BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID%>").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#<%=BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }

            }           
    </script>
```

Comment: It almost works! This is how I tested it. I selected a radio button from group book and then I selected an option from group card. The next button was enabled which was the good news! But as soon as I refreshed the page and my radio buttons was already selected when I tried clicking on the next button it was disabled because I didn't click on one of the radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: m glad i ws able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I had to add an answer that uses a `RadioButtonList` instead of 2 RadioButtons for one group, uses the aspnet `Enabled` property for the button   and is using about 1/4th of the javascript lines as the accepted answer.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioPassBook" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Book-Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Book-No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioPassCard" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Card-Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Card-No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Button ID="BtnNextRecentInfo" runat="server" Text="Next" Enabled="false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= RadioPassBook.ClientID %>, #<%= RadioPassCard.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        CheckBothRadioButtonLists();
    });

    function CheckBothRadioButtonLists() {
        if ($("input[name='<%= RadioPassBook.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null || $("input[name='<%= RadioPassCard.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null) {
            $("#<%= BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $("#<%= BtnNextRecentInfo.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here the snippet if you want to use a aspnet Validator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBothRadioButtonLists" ErrorMessage="Both lists have to be selected"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckBothRadioButtonLists(sender, element) {
        if ($("input[name='<%= RadioPassBook.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null || $("input[name='<%= RadioPassCard.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null) {
            element.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            element.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```